# How do I export my custom keyboard shortcuts as a json to use in the GNOME extension "Shortcuts"?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, dconf, gsettings

I tried using `gsettings get` on my custom keyboard shortcuts, but it came out as an .xml file. I need to get it as a .json file in order to use them with the "Shortcuts" GNOME extension (the one where you press ***Super + S*** and it shows you an overlay of all the shortcuts). I tried using an online xml to json converter but it came out all wrong.

Any ideas?